# Java parseInt error for a drawing program

Tags: java

I get the following error when running a drawing program I am working on for a peersonal project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100,"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at InputExample.main(InputExample.java:35)
```

I know what the error means, however since I am just starting out on learning Java I am not 100% how to fix it. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {

    public final static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphicsScreen g = new GraphicsScreen();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int param1 = -1;
        int param2 = -1;
        String line;
        String command;
        String[] sut;
        System.out
                .println("Please enter your commands here. A list of commands is below to help you get started.");

        do {
            System.out.println("Circle, Move, Draw");
            line = s.nextLine();
        } while(line.equalsIgnoreCase("help") == true);

        sut = line.split(" ");

        command = sut[0];

        if(sut.length > 1) {
            param1 = Integer.parseInt(sut[1]);

            if(sut.length > 2) {
                param2 = Integer.parseInt(sut[2]);
            }
        }

        if(command.equals("Move") == true) {
            g.move(param1, param2);
        }
        else if(command.equals("Draw") == true) {
            g.draw(param1, param2);
        }
        else if(command.equals("Circle") == true) {
            g.circle(param1);
        }
        else {
            System.out
                    .println("The commands you have entered are invalid. Please try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

So I've converted the integer's to numerical values and passed them through an IF statement to draw shapes on the screen. I'm guessing the error message is something really simple.

Comment: it looks like you have a comma after `100`.

Comment: what are you trying to read from the console...

It looks like there is a "," after 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to include the comma in the delimiter for your split - and perhaps make it an optional comma by using `?`:

```
sut = line.split(",? ");
```

Another alternative is to remove the comma before parsing:

```
sut[1] = sut[1].replaceAll(",$", "")
```